# Detect empty formset in template

Tags: django, django-forms

I am rendering a formset in a template. How can I write a condition such that the page displays the sentence "Nothing to show" if the formset has no elements?

The following does not work:

```
{% if formset %}
    {{ formset }}
{% else %}
    <p>Nothing to show</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just found the answer by myself... It works with `formset.forms`:

```
{% if formset.forms %}
    {{ formset }}
{% else %}
    <p>Nothing to show</p>
{% endif %}
```